# htaccess mask url with subdomain

Tags: redirect, masking, subdomain

I want to mask a url path with a subdomain.
Example:
'auto.domain.com' should redirect to 'domain.com/auto'

and after that if a menu is pressed the subdomain should remain
Example:
'auto.domain.com/busses' and not to go to 'domain.com/auto/busses'

I have managed the redirect with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule .*  http://domain.com/%1     [L,R=302]
```

But this just do the redirect not the masking.

Both domain.com and subdomain.com point to the same DOCUMENT_ROOT.
When you go to one or another without any rewrite the domain or subdomain remains in the links.
The issue is that subdomain should not go to domain.com but domain.com/auto. (auto is not a folder, its an alias from cms)

Comment: Changing [L,R=302] to [L,R=302,P] the subdomain remains but the links are going to the original path

Comment: Try without `R` flag: `RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/%1 [L,P]`

Comment: Are `auto.domain.com` and `domain.com` both on same host and pointing to same `DOCUMENT_ROOT`?

Comment: yes they both point to same document_root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since htaccess is not my strong point, i did a php header redirect:

```
$domain = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$requri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (($domain == "subdomain.domain.com") && $requri == "/" ||
($domain == "www.subdomain.domain.com")) { 
header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://domain.com/subdomain"); 
}
```

This solution is working like it's supposed to, except from some file submit issues that need some additional tweaks for the subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^subdomain.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ^subdomain/ [L]
```

Replace "subdomain" on your subdomain

Comment: This does nothing actually.

Answer (score 0):

Ok try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^.]+)\.
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

**make sure this is your first rule.**

Comment: This do the same that Lexd5 suggested. Masks the domain to subdomain.domain.com but does not do the redirect

Comment: What was the full URL you tried and what is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: domain.com and subdomain.domain.com point both to httpdocs and .htaccess is in httpdocs too

Comment: Is this the only .htaccess OR you have any other .htaccess as well? Also are there other rules in current .htaccess?

Comment: it is the only htaccess. and the only rule there is RewriteRule .* index.php. I tried to let only what you suggested but still no result.

Comment: see edited code now and **make sure this is your first rule** before your other rule.